# Splash doesn't render any JavaScript elements on website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, lua, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm using Splash in a docker server with DigitalOcean to render a website (https://www.coop.se/handla/varor/mejeri-agg/kvarg-cottage-cheese/naturell-kvarg/kvarg-naturell-7392672001403) so that it'll load the title and the rest of the page. I feel like it has something to do with JavaScript as the website looks the same as if I disabled JavaScript scripts. I'm not sure if it changes everything but I have a script to accept cookies when it first goes into the website.

When I use the render function on Splash's website I see the website and some elements of it, stuff that's probably part of the HTML but anything that's loaded by JavaScript isn't loaded, which kind of defeats the whole purpose of using Splash. I've tried disabling private mode and changing the user agent to the one of my browser, which I know works, but nothing. Is it simply a problem with my configuration or a limitation of Splash? I don't know if it's important but I have this script

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  local element = splash:select("#cmpbntyestxt")
  assert(element:mouse_click())
  assert(splash:wait(5))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

which clicks the "Accept All" cookies button.